May a convert/woman be the president or CEO of a tzedakah organization
According to Halacha, people who convert to Judaism or Jewish women  are not permitted to have some positions of authority over born Jews. My question is, does being a president or CEO of a tzedakah organization count as a position of power which they would  be barred from or no?

There are conflicting opinions as to which positions an authority a woman can have, see here on MY for many of these opinions
